# What is the performance of .net -> registry code?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, registry

Roughly speaking, what's the performance of .net code that reads/deletes keys from the Windows registry? Is it akin to file i/o?  faster?  closer to memory i/o?  slower?  closer to network i/o? (i can't imagine...just stated for completeness =)

Comment: The only way to know would be to devise a test. But really, why should it matter? Anything that accesses the registry shouldn't be time critical, so whether it takes 1 microsecond or 100 milliseconds shouldn't make a measurable difference in the runtime of your program.

Comment: @Jim - I'm automating an application that writes to the registry and I need to undo some things its doing in the registry (which the vendor has verified).  My code is time critical and depends on this third-party app.  So that app is "black-boxed" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't even start to compare network i/o with local file i/o / registry access because there are so many more factors at work.

You could in theory devise some sort of test to compare file reads with registry reads, but I don't think it will be of any benefit. This test could still be flawed because it may depend on which keys you are reading from and other apps that may also be reading the registry in the background.

If you need to access the registry then the time it takes is largely irrelevant because you have no option but to do it anyway - likewise with file i/o.

**EDIT:**

Quick Test gives the following results:

- 100,000 registry reads takes **1.81 - 1.89 s**
- 100,000 reads of a 9 byte file takes **19.80 - 20.10 s** (so registry is much (~10x) faster:)

  ```
  Dim sw As New Stopwatch

  Dim subkey As RegistryKey
  Dim value As String
  Dim keyValue As String

  sw.Reset()
  sw.Start()
  For i As Integer = 1 To 100000
      keyValue = "SOFTWARE\Codejock Software\Xtreme SuitePro ActiveX v15.0.2"
      subkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyValue, False)
      value = subkey.GetValue("Installation Directory")
  Next
  sw.Stop()
  Debug.WriteLine("Registry Read:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)

  Dim fileContents As String

  sw.Reset()
  sw.Start()
  For i As Integer = 1 To 100000
      fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\scratch\Text.txt")
  Next
  sw.Stop()
  Debug.WriteLine("File Read:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)
  ```

Comment: the same issues apply with disk i/o and network i/o (i.e. it matters what else is flying around) but that doesn't prohibit advice on those topics...I'm just trying to get a general idea.  I don't know how the registry is stored nor how .net accesses it.

Comment: I stumbled across this while doing research to answer the question of whether if I should store an encrypted DB connection string in a file or the registry and those test results just answered my question.